# GKE load-balanced service without public IP

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a GKE service with load balancer, but I want to use it internally by my other services, e.g. **I want public IP not to be assigned to it**

Is is it possible without private VPN and juggling over firewall settings?

All other load-balancing (like `kube-dns`) features work great and for services within my Container Engine do not need public IP

All nodes live in same region and zone so I do not need and do not care about multi-regional features

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't clear in the context of your question whether "internally by my other services" means "Kubernetes Services running in the same cluster" or "other applications running in GCE but outside the Kubernetes cluster".

Kubernetes "Service" resources do load balancing even when they aren't set to `LoadBalancer`. So if you only need to expose this Service to other applications running in Kubernetes, you can set the `spec.type` of the Service to `ClusterIP`. From the docs:

> ClusterIP: Exposes the service on a cluster-internal IP. Choosing this value makes the service only reachable from within the cluster.

If you need to expose this Service to applications outside of Kubernetes, you will need to set `spec.type` to `LoadBalancer` which will assign it a public IP. Firewall configuration is made relatively easy for simple firewall rules using `spec.loadBalancerSourceRanges`. You can read more about that here:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-cloud-provider-firewall/

Answer (score 7):

GKE supports [Internal Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/internal-load-balancing) now:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: [SERVICE-NAME]
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: "Internal"
  labels:
    app: echo
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: [IP-ADDRESS]
  ports:
  - port: 9000
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    [KEY]: [VALUE]
```

Notice the annotation: `cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: "Internal"`.
This will create a LoadBalancer Service with a private IP-Address routable from within your VPC.

Bitnami also has a great blog post on this:
[creating-private-kubernetes-clusters-on-gke](https://engineering.bitnami.com/articles/creating-private-kubernetes-clusters-on-gke.html).

Comment: But this is not available from the resources outside the region right? Is there any way to access this IP address from another region?

Comment: @AmitYadav, the region isn't the strict limitation. Virtual routing is configured in your VPC's.
There are a few ways to route internal addresses between VPC's.

In the past, I've used a Shared VPC for routing between GKE Nodes residing in multiple regions. These routes can be peered to an On-Premise network using the Cloud Router and Cloud VPN services.
https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/shared-vpc

Consider Global Dynamic Routing
https://cloud.google.com/router/docs/how-to/configuring-routing-mode
Also:
https://medium.com/@swongra/migrating-to-gcp-first-things-first-vpcs-c0cf00d9adff